# Is there any way to simplify various function calls from code.gs in a google.script.run.withSuccessHandler? Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, modal-dialog

I have created a modal dialog in my google sheet where you can see the data obtained from the sheet. This modal is only to read the data of the sheet in an orderly way and more aesthetically pleasing to the eye than with the cells of the sheet of google sheets.

The modal works fine but I have 1 question and it is the following:

There are several functions in my coge.gs to obtain the data from my google sheet.
At the same time, I have to call these functions in my html file with `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` to be able to get the data in my template.

Is there any way to simplify the process of function calls in a single `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` ?

This is my code html:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('nombreclientePE').textContent = value;} ).clientePedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('numeropedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).numeroPedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('fechapedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).fechaPedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('estadopedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).estadoPedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('logometodopagopedidoPE').src = value;} ).logoMetodoPagoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('metodopagopedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).metodoPagoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('gastosenviopedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).gastosEnvioPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('metodoenviopedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).metodoEnvioPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('subtotalpedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).subtotalPedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('decuentocantidad%pedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).descuentoCantidadPorcentajePedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('decuentocantidad€pedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).descuentoCantidadEurosPedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('decuentototalpedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).descuentoTotalPedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('totalpedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).totalPedidoPE();
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (value) {document.getElementById('direccionpedidoPE').textContent = value;} ).direccionEnvioPE();
```

Link to a google sheet document with the live demo.
To open the modal window, the active cell must be positioned in any cell of any customer row. Then, click on the "View order" button.

[Google Sheets Demo Live](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13o5-TPeQB0AslUfhaPCFPgV_uC65ivyVGM1Fy3vlhD0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

**Code.gs**

```js
const o = {
  'nombreclientePE': () => clientePedidoPE(),
  'numeropedidoPE': () => numeroPedidoPE(),
  'fechapedidoPE': () => fechaPedidoPE(),
  'estadopedidoPE': () => estadoPedidoPE(),
  'logometodopagopedidoPE': () => logoMetodoPagoPE(),
  'metodopagopedidoPE': () => metodoPagoPE(),
  'gastosenviopedidoPE': () => gastosEnvioPE(),
  'metodoenviopedidoPE': () => metodoEnvioPE(),
  'subtotalpedidoPE': () => subtotalPedidoPE(),
  'decuentocantidad%pedidoPE': () => descuentoCantidadPorcentajePedidoPE(),
  'decuentocantidad€pedidoPE': () => descuentoCantidadEurosPedidoPE(),
  'decuentototalpedidoPE': () => descuentoTotalPedidoPE(),
  'totalpedidoPE': () => totalPedidoPE(),
  'direccionpedidoPE': () => direccionEnvioPE()
};

function PE(input) {
  const output = [];
  for (const id of input) {
    const value = o[id]();
    output.push([id, value]);
  }
  return output;
}

function formVerPedido2(numPedido) {
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var fila = hoja.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var numPedido = hoja.getRange(fila,3,1,1).getValue();
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('PedidosIndex');
  template.input = Object.keys(o);
  var pedidoContendido = template.evaluate()
    .setWidth(800)
    .setHeight(1300);


  //var logoMetodoPago = logoMetodoPagoPE();
  //htmlOutput = logoMetodoPago;

 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(pedidoContendido, 'Pedido #' + numPedido + '');
}
```

**index.html**

```html
    <script>const input = <?!= JSON.stringify(input) ?>;</script>
    <?!= include('PedidosJavaScript'); ?> <!-- See PedidosJavaScript.html file -->
```

**js.html**

```js
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).PE(input);
function onSuccess(output) {
  for (const [id, value] of output) {
    document.getElementById(id).textContent = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work in my case. I can't get any value from the spreadsheet. @idfurw

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have written in my initial comment the link to a google sheet document with the live demo. To open the modal window, the active cell must be positioned in any cell of any customer row. Then, click on the "View order" button. @idfurw

Comment: Should you use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`? I found that you are returning `<br>`

Comment: Modified and tested. Please check.

Comment: With the new code it generates an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'evaluate' of undefined` and the modal is not opened. This error is generated from the function `formVerPedido2` .  I'm going to try `innerHTML` and I'll tell you. By the way, thank you very much for your time and great help.  @idfurw

Comment: Modified `formVerPedido2`.

Comment: With the new modification, now if you open the modal. however, in the first order (ref. 105) the data from the spreadsheet is not obtained. With the second order (ref. 106) if the data from the spreadsheet is displayed except the data `'logometodopagopedidoPE': () => logoMetodoPagoPE (),` The same thing happens with the third order (ref. 107) as with the second order (ref. 106). @idfurw

Comment: On the other hand, I have tried innerHTML as you suggested, however it only performs the first line break `\n` and the last one `\n` . The intermediate line breaks are not executed, so the address (at the end of the modal) is not displayed correctly. The two intermediate lines are shown in "inline" mode. I thought that the `innerHTML` disabled escaping. Now I don't know how to interpret it. Disable escape halfway...? Do you know any that the intermediate line breaks are executed? @idfurw

Comment: You should use `\n` for `textContent` while `<br>` for `innerHTML`. I suggest it because I saw a `<br>` displayed in text. You should settle it youself.

Comment: There is a space before `()` of `logoMetodoPagoPE ()` in your comment. Please double check your script.

Comment: I did not know that. I already changed all the `\ n` to `<br>` . Thanks, something new I learned. Regarding the `'logometodopagopedidoPE': () => logoMetodoPagoPE(),` , here in the comment it stuck badly because the translator put the space, but in my code in google apps script, it is written correctly, without space. The modal problem persists and I don't know what may be the cause for it to get the data for the other two orders but not for the first order. And the problem of getting `logoMetodoPagoPE()` too . However, this problem does not occur with my original code.  @idfurw

Comment: No, I have checked `direccionEnvioPE`. It is a problem of your function. 1. There is no `Maria del Campo` (first order) in sheet `Clientes`; 2. `busqueda = -1`; 3. `tablaDeBusqueda[-1][8]` gives error.

Answer (score 1):

If informations are coming from a form : code html

```
  function formSubmit() {
    var data = document.forms[0]
    var tab = []
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      if (data[i].type != "button"){
        tab.push(data[i].value)
      }
    }
    google.script.run.addData(tab);
    document.forms[0].reset()
  }
```

code gs

```
function addData(tab) {
  mySheet.getRange(getLastDataRow(bdd) + 1,1,1,tab.length).setValues([tab])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and your code however the data does not come from a form. What I am doing is displaying the data from the google sheet in a modaldialog. In this way, it looks much more orderly and it is easier for me to view all the information at once, without having to scroll to the side or down through the google sheet.  @MikeSteelson

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding ... I will post a new version.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is : replace all the functions as numeroPedidoPE(), fechaPedidoPE() ... by only one (assuming that data are in the same row)

```
function transferPedidoData() {
  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var fila = hoja.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var pedidoData = hoja.getRange('B'+fila+':S'+fila).getValues();
  return pedidoData;
}
```

then, in the html file, add this script

```
<script>
  <? 
    var pedido = transferPedidoData();
  ?>
</script>
```

and finally, call for the different data in your PedidosHTML.html file as following, x as needed

```
<?= pedido[0][x] ?>
```

- little demo here (I have added 2 files because I wouldn't like to modifiy your script) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNMs99gOhH5WfrutYWo08o4jGOztFIBFQGbjpaYfSjQ/edit?usp=sharing
- edit = I also tried to implement this method in your spreadsheet, hope this helps you in understanding (so there is only one call to GSheet) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CtZJNYEVJLkexB1PCiy0c4liJT72iOxWQhS1W93khT8/edit?usp=sharing
- to transfer data from 'clientes',  leave `function direccionEnvioPE()`as is, add in html `var direccionEnvio = direccionEnvioPE();` and use addresses as following `<?= direccionEnvio ?>`

Comment: Your code works very well and the best thing is that I am saving a lot of calls with it.
However I have a query. I was trying to reproduce the same scenario but to get the data from the "customers" sheet, to get the shipping and billing address of the same customer. That is, with map() and indexof() I collect the search, however I don't know how to get the variables for the html template. I did tests following your example but I couldn't get it to work. I must be overlooking something. I'm stuck. Do you think you could help me? I open a new thread and leave the link here? @MikeSteelson

Comment: leave the link here, I will have a look at it as soon as possible (but may be tomoroww French Time)

Comment: take a new copy of demo https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNMs99gOhH5WfrutYWo08o4jGOztFIBFQGbjpaYfSjQ/edit?usp=sharing I have updated the solution ... you will then have 2 calls from your spreadsheet.

Comment: you can also transfer the complete row of 'Clientes', see variant in demo spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

This definitely needs to be simplified. On the client side you need something like this:

```js
function gscriptRun(fnName) {
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function (value) {
      document.getElementById(fnName).textContent = value;
    })
    .runFunc(fnName);
}

const fnsToRun = ['clientePedidoPE', 'numeroPedidoPE'];
fnsToRun.forEach(fn => gscriptRun(fn));
```

We wrapping all `google.script.run` calls in a function. Then we create an array of function names we want to call on the server side and call them all with `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

On the server side you need to have this function:

```js
function runFunc(fnName) {
  return globalThis[fnName]();
}
```

It will just execute the functions by their names.

However, this doesn't look like a great approach as there are so many API calls. You probably want to re-write your code so that you can extract all data with just one call.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have written
in my initial comment the link to a google sheet document with the live demo.
To open the modal window, the active cell must be positioned in any cell of any customer row. Then, click on the "View order" button.  @DmitryKostyuk

Comment: Well you have yet to provide any of the code for your functions so we don't really know  any of the specifics of what you are doing.   This is that approach I would prefer unless there is some specific reason why each value needs a different function other than because I don't know what I doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this type of structure if you want to grab the values from various locations in a spreadsheet.  Personally I would put them right next to each other in a row and use getValues() instead of getting each value separately.

gs:

```
function getMyData(tA) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rgObj = {'nombreclientePE':'A1','numeropedidoPE':'A2','fechapedidoPE':'A3','estadopedidoPE':'A4','logometodopagopedidoPE':'A5','metodopagopedidoPE':'A6','gastosenviopedidoPE':'A7','metodoenviopedidoPE':'A8','subtotalpedidoPE':'A9','decuentocantidad%pedidoPE':'A10','decuentocantidad€pedidoPE':'A11','decuentototalpedidoPE':'A12','totalpedidoPE':'A13','direccionpedidoPE':'A14'}
  let obj = {pA:[]}
  tA.forEach(p => {
    obj.pA.push(p);
    obj[p] = sh.getRange(rgObj[p]).getValue();
  });
  return obj;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>My Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <!-- You provide the body -->
     <script>
       window.onload = getData()
       function getData() {
         const tA = ['nombreclientePE','numeropedidoPE','fechapedidoPE','estadopedidoPE','logometodopagopedidoPE','metodopagopedidoPE','gastosenviopedidoPE','metodoenviopedidoPE','subtotalpedidoPE','decuentocantidad%pedidoPE','decuentocantidad€pedidoPE','decuentototalpedidoPE','totalpedidoPE','direccionpedidoPE'];
         google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler((obj) => {
           obj.pA.forEach(p => {
             document.getElementById(e).textContent = obj[p];
           })
         })
         .getMyData(tA) 
       }
     </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I have written in my initial comment the link to a google sheet document with the live demo. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I have followed your steps and I have collected all the values in the same function. Still it doesn't work. The only method that works for me is the way I had it. Collect the values in different functions and call these functions via google.script.run.with...  @Cooper

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way of doing this from what you already have is use a single `google.script.run` call to a wrapper function which returns all the data and then setting the values in JavaScript.

List your elements in an array and then loop through them on Success, rather than using a `google.script.run` call for each element:

```
const elements = [
      'nombreclientePE',
      'numeropedidoPE',
      'fechapedidoPE',
      'estadopedidoPE',
      'metodopagopedidoPE',
      'gastosenviopedidoPE',
      'metodoenviopedidoPE',
      'subtotalpedidoPE',
      'decuentocantidad%pedidoPE',
      'decuentocantidad€pedidoPE',
      'decuentototalpedidoPE',
      'totalpedidoPE',
      'direccionpedidoPE',
    ]
    
    const logoId = 'logometodopagopedidoPE'
    
    function callGasFn() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setData).getAllValues()
    }
    
    function setData(data) {
      elements.forEach((x, i) => document.getElementById(x).textContent = data[0][i])
      document.getElementById(logoId) = data[1]
    }
   
    callGasFn()
```

Then in Apps Script you have your `getAllValues()` function:

```
function getAllValues() {
  return [
    [
      clientePedidoPE(),
      numeroPedidoPE(),
      fechaPedidoPE(),
      estadoPedidoPE(),
      metodoPagoPE(),
      gastosEnvioPE(),
      metodoEnvioPE(),
      subtotalPedidoPE(),
      descuentoCantidadPorcentajePedidoPE(),
      descuentoCantidadEurosPedidoPE(),
      descuentoTotalPedidoPE(),
      totalPedidoPE(),
      direccionEnvioPE(),
    ],
    logoMetodoPagoPE()
  ]
}
```

I separated the logo out of the main array as it has `src` set as opposed to `textContent`.

In the sheet you provided, `Maria del Campo` is missing from the client sheet - I don't know if this is intened but it does cause `direccionEnvioPE()` to fail as her data isn't available in the sheet.